Shrinkwrap and subdividion creates issues on mirrored side
Learning Blender and having some trouble. I've sculpted a character and then applied mirror, shrinkwrap and subdivision modifiers to create a lower resolution retopologized mesh. The issues comes up with the hands, where the shrinkwrap and subdivison creates some kind of distortion when they are applied together. Curiously, the issues are only really visible on the mirrored side, not the "true" side.
Here is the retopologized mesh on the true side; looks fine (I think?)

But on the other side...

I've tried recalculating the normals and Clean up -> Merge by Distance, though I don't really know what the really does. Could there be an issue with symmetry? Why would they not be symmetrical when there is a mirror modifier applied? Could the sculpt underneath be slightly asymmetrical, making the shrinkwrap and subdivison slightly different on the other side, even though the vertices are symmetric? Is there a way to check the symmetry of the sculpt?
I also noticed something when viewing it in X-ray mode; there are some spikes inside the mesh (in the knuckles), even on the "good" side. Is it related, or a seperate issue?


Can this be salvaged? Any insight is much appreciated,
Thanks in advance!
EDIT: I solved the issue with internal spiked on the true side, but they still appear on the mirrored side.

First off, how would shrinkwrap and subdivision surface produce a lower poly mesh? Shrink wrap needs a target, and SS adds vertices.

Sorry, I might be getting the terms wrong! I'm following an online course, and the term they use for the target of the shrinkwrap is "sculpt". As in the model we created with the sculpt tool. The new mesh is a retopologised version of this sculpt. So a basic cube mesh was shrinkwrapped around to the sculpt, then it was subdivided, giving a resulting mesh tht is somewhere between a straight shrinkwrapped cube and the "sculpt". Does that make sense?

Yes, it does. I think you might save some time though by using the remesh modifier instead. The method you describe sounds very crude, though maybe I’m missing a step.
